# KeyError: 'A2142A2744A2199A119'

Tags: python, pandas

I try to make the "cluster" read one by one base of the dataframe below but I couldn't get to that, I try to use `for` too but I still cannot get what I expected. So I try to used this method and I get that error. I hope you guys can give some ideas to solve this error.

````
from scipy import constants
from qconstants import *
import os.path
import pandas as pd

cluster = 'A2142'
cluster += 'A2744'
cluster += 'A2199'
cluster += 'A119'

################ List of Cluster##################################################################

d1=pd.DataFrame.from_items([
('A2142'  ,['A2142' ,'MH',0.0909 ,418600 ,23 ,129 ,0.57 ,0.810 ,5.82 ,10.0 ,0.5 ,6189.32 ,510 ,2000]),
('A2744'  ,['A2744' ,'RH',0.3080 , 28840, 218, 115, 7.7, 0.680, 10.8, 10.0, 0.5, 920.667, 1360, 1100]),
('A2199'  ,['A2199' ,'RH',0.0302 , 127000 ,250 , 99.3, 2.0, 0.655, 10.1, 11.7, 0.9, 14655.02, 180, 1000.0]),
('A119'   ,['A119'  ,'RH',0.0440 ,832000, 243 , 357.9, 5.8, 0.675, 0.15, 7.5, 0.9, 5627.63, 5770, 1100.0])],
orient='index',columns=['Label','type','redshift','DL','S_nu','r_c_dum','T_gas_dum','beta','n0','B_dum','eta','rho_s','r_s','r'])


############################# Set and decide the constants start ##################################################

#Hubble constants
h       =0.7        #little h.      unit :  -

#Critical density:
sigm        =0.3        #matter density.    unit :  -
sigl        =0.7        #dark energy density.   unit :  -
sig8        =0.829

#Properties of cluster:
redshift    =d1.loc[cluster,'redshift']
DL      =d1.loc[cluster,'DL']*kpc*100.0 # luminosity distance, in unit of cm.   z=0.0302
#DA     =100000*kpc*100.0
S_nu            =d1.loc[cluster,'S_nu']            #mJy
r_c_dum =d1.loc[cluster,'r_c_dum']      #Core radius.       unit :  h50^-1 kpc, where H0=50 kms^-1Mpc^-1
T_gas_dum   =d1.loc[cluster,'T_gas_dum']        #T_gas in unit of keV
beta        =d1.loc[cluster,'beta']     #Beta parameter.    unit :  -
n0      =d1.loc[cluster,'n0']       #Thermal electron central density   #unit : cm^-3. A&A 540, A38 (2012)
B_dum       =d1.loc[cluster,'B_dum']    #central magnetic field.        #unit : Gauss.  A&A 540, A38 (2012)
eta     =d1.loc[cluster,'eta']      #proportional coefficient related to magnetic field profile

#Temperature of CMB at any redshift z. (want ot know more? See http://www.cv.nrao.edu/course/astr534/CMB.html)
T       =T0*(1.0+redshift)

#conversion if necessary
B0  =B_dum*(10**-6)
H_0 =100.0*h                #hubble constant.   unit :  km s^-1 Mpc^-1
H_0m    =H_0/(1000.0*si_pc)         #hubble constant.   unit :  s^-1
Ez  =np.sqrt(sigm*(1.0+redshift)**3+sigl)
Hz  =H_0m*Ez                #H(z).          unit :  s^-1
rho_crit=3.0*Hz**2/(8.0*constants.pi*si_G)  #critical density.  unit :  kg m^-3

T_gas   =T_gas_dum*1000.0*si_e/si_k     #T_gas in unit of Kelvin
r_c_dum2=r_c_dum*0.5/h              #Core radius.       unit :  kpc, where h=0.673
r_c =r_c_dum2*1000.0*si_pc*100.0        #Core radius.       unit :  cm

############################# Set and decide the constants end ####################################################
############################# start: parameters for nfw profile ####################################################
#characteristic density in unit of kg m^-3  ( multiplied by rho_crit )
rho_s=d1.loc[cluster,'rho_s']*rho_crit
#characteristic radius in unit of meter
r_s= kpc*d1.loc[cluster,'r_s']
r=kpc*d1.loc[cluster,'r']
############################# end: parameters for nfw profile ####################################################```
````

Comment: from_items() has been deprecated in newer pythons... use dict().

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not well written.

Seems you are trying to do some computations `per row` (you call cluster).
Or are you trying to do some `N row computation`?

The final desired outcome is not clear? What is `nfw profile`?

Are you trying to build additional columns?  or arrive at some transformed data?

Below is you code re-written using df.apply() to do per row to show per row computation.  (`more clean up work is needed`)

The code is missing several items so I defaulted all of them to 1.0 `T0=1.0, si_pc = 1.0, si_G = 1.0, si_e = 1.0, si_k = 1.0, kpc=1.0, rho=1.0`.

#### Create DataFrame example

```
import numpy as np

items= [
('A2142'  ,['A2142' ,'MH',0.0909 ,418600 ,23 ,129 ,0.57 ,0.810 ,5.82 ,10.0 ,0.5 ,6189.32 ,510 ,2000]),
('A2744'  ,['A2744' ,'RH',0.3080 , 28840, 218, 115, 7.7, 0.680, 10.8, 10.0, 0.5, 920.667, 1360, 1100]),
('A2199'  ,['A2199' ,'RH',0.0302 , 127000 ,250 , 99.3, 2.0, 0.655, 10.1, 11.7, 0.9, 14655.02, 180, 1000.0]),
('A119'   ,['A119'  ,'RH',0.0440 ,832000, 243 , 357.9, 5.8, 0.675, 0.15, 7.5, 0.9, 5627.63, 5770, 1100.0])]

d1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({k:v for k,v in items},
orient='index',columns=['Label','type','redshift','DL','S_nu','r_c_dum','T_gas_dum','beta','n0','B_dum','eta','rho_s','r_s','r'])
```

#### `perRow` - Function to apply per row

````
def perRow(r, T0=1.0, si_pc = 1.0, si_G = 1.0, si_e = 1.0, si_k = 1.0, kpc=1.0, rho=1.0):


    ############################# Set and decide the constants start ##################################################

    #Hubble constants
    h       =0.7        #little h.      unit :  -

    #Critical density:
    sigm        =0.3        #matter density.    unit :  -
    sigl        =0.7        #dark energy density.   unit :  -
    sig8        =0.829

    #Properties of cluster:
    #redshift    = r.redshift
    #DL          = r.DL *kpc*100.0 # luminosity distance, in unit of cm.   z=0.0302
    #DA     =100000*kpc*100.0
    #S_nu        =r.S_nu
    #r_c_dum     = r.r_c_dum     #Core radius.       unit :  h50^-1 kpc, where H0=50 kms^-1Mpc^-1
    #T_gas_dum   = r.T_gas_dum   #T_gas in unit of keV
    #beta        = r.beta        #Beta parameter.    unit :  -
    #n0          = r.n0          #Thermal electron central density   #unit : cm^-3. A&A 540, A38 (2012)
    #B_dum       = r.B_dum       #central magnetic field.        #unit : Gauss.  A&A 540, A38 (2012)
    #eta         = r.eta         #proportional coefficient related to magnetic field profile

    #Temperature of CMB at any redshift z. (want ot know more? See http://www.cv.nrao.edu/course/astr534/CMB.html)
    T       =T0*(1.0+r.redshift)

    #conversion if necessary
    B0    = r.B_dum*(10**-6)
    H_0   =100.0*h                #hubble constant.   unit :  km s^-1 Mpc^-1
    H_0m  =H_0/(1000.0*si_pc)         #hubble constant.   unit :  s^-1
    Ez    =np.sqrt(sigm*(1.0+r.redshift)**3+sigl)
    Hz    =H_0m*Ez                #H(z).          unit :  s^-1
    # FIXME: used np.pi instead of constants.pi
    rho_crit=3.0*Hz**2/(8.0*np.pi*si_G)  #critical density.  unit :  kg m^-3

    T_gas   = r.T_gas_dum*1000.0*si_e/si_k     #T_gas in unit of Kelvin
    r_c_dum2= r.r_c_dum*0.5/h              #Core radius.       unit :  kpc, where h=0.673
    r_c = r_c_dum2*1000.0*si_pc*100.0        #Core radius.       unit :  cm

    ############################# Set and decide the constants end ####################################################
    ############################# start: parameters for nfw profile ####################################################
    #characteristic density in unit of kg m^-3  ( multiplied by rho_crit )
    rho_s= r.rho_s*rho_crit
    #characteristic radius in unit of meter
    r_s= kpc* r.r_s
    r=kpc*r.r
    ############################# end: parameters for nfw profile ####################################################```
    nfw_profile = [rho_s, r_s, r]
    return(nfw_profile)
````

#### Apply `perRow()` to each row of d1 dataframe.

```
print("\n NFW PROFILE [rho_s, r_s, r]")
print(d1.apply(lambda r: perRow(r),axis=1))
```

#### OUTPUT

```
 NFW PROFILE [rho_s, r_s, r]
A2142      [3.943995655495191, 510.0, 2000.0]
A2744    [0.7384586065967704, 1360.0, 1100.0]
A2199      [8.811723258555253, 180.0, 1000.0]
A119      [3.427734855427434, 5770.0, 1100.0]
dtype: object
```